# How to "hide" ommit Babel/Webpack/Plugins configuration files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I'm building my very own boilerplate starter kit for React + Redux development and wanted to know if there is a way to hide webpack.config.js and .babelrc files?

For example under the hood the create-react-app also has webpack.config.js and .babelrc files but they are hidden until the npm run eject command. How can I do that in a similar way?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Facebook's Create React App does this by adding it as a npm package. You can see the package here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app or on NPM here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts.

Then when you build it runs the build scripts inside of the package. I'd put good thought into forking what they have if you are really going down this path and then pull in their updates in a base branch and play forward your modifications.